# Working in a SDN enviroment with RYU and OVS

Tags: ryu

has anyone worked with RYU and OVS and tried to manage an OVS switch that runs in another PC than where the RYU is located? We are able to obtain data from these switches with the commands of the ovs-vsctl package but we are not able to generate traffic between two switches that are outside the PC where the RYU runs. The switches have connection to the RYU, and the it can manage them.

We want to generate traffic between this two switchs OVS with commands of Open Flow. 
We are working with Ubuntu and Python scripts.

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a detailed description of your topology, like an image or something like this?